# How to create a service account to get a list of pods from inside a Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

I have created a service account to get a list of pods in minikube.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: demo-sa
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: list-pods
  namespace: default
rules:
  - apiGroups:
    - ''
    resources:
      - pods
    verbs:
      - list
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
 name: list-pods_demo-sa
 namespace: default
roleRef:
 kind: Role
 name: list-pods
 apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: demo-sa
    namespace: default
```

The problem is, that I get an error message if I use the service account to get the list of pods. `kubectl auth can-i list pod --as demo-sa` answers always with `no`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use:

```
kubectl auth can-i list pod --as <something>
```

to impersonate ServiceAccounts. You can only impersonate users `--as` and impersonate groups `--as-group`

A workaround is to use the [service account token](https://success.docker.com/article/how-to-troubleshoot-kubernetes-serviceaccount-permissions).

```sh
kubectl get secret demo-sa-token-7fx44 -o=jsonpath='{.data.token}' | base64 -d
```

You can use the output here and any `kubectl` request. However, I checked with `kubectl auth can-i list pod` and I don't think `auth` works with a token (you always get a yes)